# Why is req.params returning 'undefined'?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, mongoose

I have a simple comments app which enables the user to enter a comment into the system via a form and these are then logged onto a list on the bottom of the page.

I wanted to modify it so that a user could click a comments title once it is created and it would load up the associated content that goes with that comment.

I have modified my route in the app.js to lookup the `:id`:

And have also modified my main **Show.js** route to use the `id` as an argument in a `findOne` command to locate the comment.

I have also put in a `console.log()` command to log out the `req.params.id`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', Comment);

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        Comment.findOne({ id: req.params.id }, function(err, comment){
            console.log(req.params.id)
        });
});

module.exports = router;
```

However, all I am getting back is an `undefined` message in my terminal.

If I place the `console.log()` directly in my app.js, I get the id logged as intended.

```
app.use('/:id', function(req,res) {
    console.log(req.params.id)
});
```

Am I missing something in my route that is stopping my from getting the id parameter?

Comment: `router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {` ???

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the `:id` in your get route, like this:

```
// GET /1 -> print 1
router.get('/:id', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.id);
});
// GET /foo/1/bar/2 -> print 1, print 2
router.get('/foo/:id1/bar/:id2', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.id1);
    console.log(req.params.id2);
});
```

Comment: @Keva161 did this help any?

Comment: Hi , 
Suppose "/mobile/custom/******/deviceVersion/:deviceType" is my request .
could you please tell me how to check "deviceType" against undefined?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass {mergeParams: true} when calling your router in the router page

```
    var router = express.router({mergeParams: true})
```

this will pass the parent parameters to the child.

Comment: Hi , 
Suppose "/mobile/custom/******/deviceVersion/:deviceType" is my request .
could you please tell me how to check "deviceType" against undefined?